# SQL query to find out third highest salary involving two tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

**Persons:**

```
empid(primary key)
firstname
lastname
email
```

**Details:**

```
Did(primary key)
salary
designation
empid
```

Now I want to select firstname, lastname, salary of the employee with the 3rd highest salary.

KEEP IT SIMPLE SINCE I AM A BEGINNER.

Also it would be great if you can suggest me a site where I can find SQL query exercises with solutions (I do not need an online interpreter, I have SQL Server 2008 to practice on ), I have completed w3schools (which was awesome) but I need exercises now, I tried sql.ex.ru but it was not that helpful.

Comment: This sounds like homework. What have you tried so for? For nice SQL exercises check out http://sqlzoo.net/

Comment: A little help there: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: Some more help: you need to join your tables, do a count, order by salary descending, and use the top function.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT   top 1 P.*,a.salary 
FROM     Persons p
JOIN
         (select top 3 empid,salary from Details order by salary desc)a
ON       p.empid=a.empid
ORDER BY p.salary
```

or

```
;WITH CTE AS
 (SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS ROW_NUM
 FROM DETAILS)
 SELECT * 
 FROM  PERSONS P
 JOIN  CTE C
 ON    P.EMPID=C.EMPID
 where c.ROW_NUM=3
```

Comment: THanks! but i just found a simpler version through trial and error method ! Thanks anyways!

Comment: just did see if there is any loophole in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little trick.  What it does is add a sequence number or row number onto each row, giving the ordering by salary.  It then just chooses the third one:

```
select FirstName, LastName, Salary
from (select p.FirstName, p.LastName, d.salary,
             row_number() over (order by salary desc) as seqnum
      from persons p join
           details d
           on p.empid = d.empid
     ) t
where seqnum = 3
```

The row_number() function does this calculation.  It is a very useful function, that you can add to your SQL knowledge.

Comment: Its a useful tip for a beginner like me , umm one question though what 't' for?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 persons.FirstName, persons.LastName, Salary 
FROM persons inner join Details
ON persons.empid=Details.empid 
where Salary not in(SELECT TOP 2 Salary from Details ORDER BY Salary DESC)
order by Salary desc
```

Comment: This is the answers i found myself, if anybody sees any loophole do correct me.